# force authentication when building on team foundation server

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I would like to know if there is a way to force a user to re-authenticate when queueing a new build on Team Foundation Server.

Right now our Production and Staging builds live on the same TFS server.  Queueing new builds on Staging isn't an issue, but it's too easy to hit Production by accident and then untested changes go into play.

So ideally the steps would be:

1) Right click the Build.
2) Queue new build.
3) Re-authenticate.
4) Continue.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is no. You could set different security on the build definitions, but this would require connecting with different credentials in the first place.

My $0.02 is that it sounds like you aren't trying to solve an access issue, but an "Oops!" issue. An easy way to solve this is to make your workflow depend on a parameter being set to a particular value. Then when the build is queued, if the person queuing the build doesn't type in the value, the build can be forced to "fail" before it even gets off the application tier.